# Changing view controller when label is certain text?

Tags: iphone, xcode, if-statement, text, label

I have a QR code reader that will change the label of a text whenever it scans something. For example, if I scan a QR code for "nfl.com" it will display "nfl.com" on the label. I want to switch controllers whenever a certain text appears on the label. This text would basically be an account number so you scan the QR code, the account number appears, it automatically changes you to a different view controller where an array of items for that account number appears.

Comment: Is this text a specific string (ex: "Hello, World" would move to new controller), an array of strings that have a specific result, or a any string?

Comment: Where are you setting the label?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the string is equal to a specific string, you could do something like the following when you set the text of the label:

```
label.text = string;

if ([string isEqualToString:@"Specific String"]) {
    ExampleViewController *exampleViewController = [[ExampleViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:exampleViewController animated:YES
}
```

If you want a delay so that it shows the label, then after a delay push the next view controller you could do the following:

```
label.text = string;

double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"Specific String"]) {
        ExampleViewController *exampleViewController = [[ExampleViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:exampleViewController animated:YES
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
    [_lblStatus performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[metadataObj stringValue] waitUntilDone:NO];


        if ([_lblStatus isEqual:@"A123"]) {
            NSString * storyboardName = @"Main_iPhone";
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
            UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CheckViewController"];
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
```

I do get the label to change to A123 but I cannot get a switch to a different view controller to happen after this. I tried your answer @ferris but I cannot set my _lblStatus = string; (string results in an error unless I define it in my .h file.